# Change cursor on disabled label

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm messing around with this css and can't figure out how to override the control class cursor attribute ('pointer') if the input inside of it is disabled. Can somebody help me out?

[Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/nickmuth/pen/dOewwW)

```
<label class="control control--checkbox">Disabled
    <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled"/>
    <div class="control__indicator"></div>
</label>

.control {
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.control__indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #e6e6e6;
}
```

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
/* Disabled state */
.control input:disabled ~ .control__indicator {

  cursor: not-allowed;
    opacity: .6;
    background: red;
}
```

so the thing is you need to remove `pointer-events:none`

read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Answer (score 1):

Refer to attributes in CSS using square brackets. Here's an example:

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
input {
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[disabled] {
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<label>
  Enabled
  <input type="checkbox">
</label>

<label>
  Disabled
  <input type="checkbox" disabled>
</label>
```

Note that with CSS alone, you won't be able to restyle the parent of the `input` based on its state, but you could restyle a sibling that comes after it in the DOM:

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
input[disabled] ~ span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>Enabled</span>
</label>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" disabled>
  <span>Disabled</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you cannot use `:has` in css you can not declare parents style by child. So remove the `cursor: pointer;` from the `label` and give it to all the siblings of checkbox including checkbox and use the successor selector `~` to specify the style

```css
.control {
 font-size: 18px;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 padding-left: 30px;
}

.control input {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 opacity: 0;
}

.control__indicator {
 position: absolute;
 top: 2px;
 left: 0;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 background: #e6e6e6;
}

.control--radio .control__indicator {
 border-radius: 50%;
}

/* Hover and focus states */
.control:hover input ~ .control__indicator,
.control input:focus ~ .control__indicator {
 background: #ccc;
}

/* Checked state */
.control input:checked ~ .control__indicator {
 background: #5579FB;
}

/* Hover state whilst checked */
.control:hover input:not([disabled]):checked ~ .control__indicator,
.control input:checked:focus ~ .control__indicator {
 background: #5579FB;
}

/* Disabled state */
.control input:disabled ~ .control__indicator {
 pointer-events: none;
 opacity: .6;
 background: #e6e6e6;
}

/* Check mark */
.control__indicator:after {
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
 content: '';
}

/* Show check mark */
.control input:checked ~ .control__indicator:after {
 display: block;
}

/* Checkbox tick */
.control--checkbox .control__indicator:after {
 top: 4px;
 left: 8px;
 width: 3px;
 height: 8px;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 border: solid #fff;
 border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

/* Disabled tick colour */
.control--checkbox input:disabled ~ .control__indicator:after {
 border-color: #7b7b7b;
}

/* Radio button inner circle */
.control--radio .control__indicator:after {
 top: 7px;
 left: 7px;
 width: 6px;
 height: 6px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: #fff;
}

/* Disabled circle colour */
.control--radio input:disabled ~ .control__indicator:after {
 background: #7b7b7b;
}

label {
  display: block;
}
input[disabled] ~ .control__indicator {
  color: red;
  cursor:not-allowed;
}
input, input ~ * {
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[disabled], input[disabled] ~ * {
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div class="control-group">
 <label class="control control--checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
    <span>First checkbox</span>
  <div class="control__indicator"></div>
 </label>
 <label class="control control--checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox"/>
    <span>Second checkbox</span>
    
  <div class="control__indicator"></div>
 </label>
 <label class="control control--checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled"/>
    <span>Disabled</span>
    
  <div class="control__indicator"></div>
 </label>
 <label class="control control--checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked"/>
    <span>Disabled & checked</span>
    
  <div class="control__indicator"></div>
 </label>
</div>


<div class="control-group">
 <label class="control control--radio">
  <input type="radio" name="radio" checked="checked"/>
    <span>First radio</span>
    
  <div class="control__indicator"></div>
 </label>
 <label class="control control--radio">
  <input type="radio" name="radio"/>
    <span>Second radio</span>
    
  <div class="control__indicator"></div>
 </label>
 <label class="control control--radio">
  <input type="radio" name="radio2" disabled="disabled"/>
    <span>Disabled</span>
    
  <div class="control__indicator"></div>
 </label>
 <label class="control control--radio">
  <input type="radio" name="radio2" disabled="disabled" checked="checked"/>
    <span>Disabled & checked</span>
  <div class="control__indicator"></div>
 </label>
</div>
```